# How to type Devanagari using LaTeX (Overleaf)?

Tags: latex, devanagari

I am trying type Devanagari Script in LaTeX using Overleaf. But I am getting some formatting error. The "matras" are not reflecting in the output Devanagari text.

```
\usepackage{devanagari}
{\dn karma}
```

Output is as follows:

[image: Word Karma]

but it should be

[image: Should be]

Comment: *Some* error? What error?

Comment: Formatting is incorrect. I have uploaded what it should be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pre-process your input data. If you have a file `karma.dn`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{devanagari}

\begin{document}
{\dn karma}

\end{document}
```

and call

```
devnag karma.dn
```

you get `karma.tex` like this:

```
\def\DevnagVersion{2.16}\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{devanagari}

\begin{document}
{\dn km\0}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

The `devnag` program comes with the LaTeX package. It might be easier to use a Unicode capable LaTeX engine like XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX together with suitable fonts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your own .dn file and then input the file in LaTeX. This should solve the matra problem as in making the .dn file, it will add matras phonetically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write **Devanagari** (Hindi) in **pdflatex** then go through this GitHub [link](https://github.com/GussailRaat/Devanagari-Hindi-Language-in-pdfLatex).

**Input:** मै तुमसे बहुत प्यार करता हूँ।

**Output:** {\dn m\4 \7{t}ms? b\7{h}t =yAr krtA \8{h}\1. }